# EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, angular-routing

- I am trying to learn angular2
- I am trying to replace window.location.href with that.router.navigate when I am doing I am getting the below error.

```or-tag-here
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'https%3A/login.stg.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp%3Freferrer%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fjumping-auth.login.dancing.isports.com/logout.do%3Fredirect%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fqa.jumping.swimming.isports.com%26client_id%3Doooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'
```

- can you tell me how to fix it...
- providing part of the code below and
- whole code in the codepen
- can you please help
- i tried all the possible ways
- can you tell me how to implement

https://codepen.io/arar/pen/qVvwaL

```or-tag-here
logOut(): void {
        let that = this;
        $(".kendoContent").text('Are you sure you want to exit the application?');
        let newdialog = $("#logOutDialog").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
        $("#logoutYes").unbind().click(function () {
            let userId;
            let attributes = that.sportsservice.getSeesionStorageValue();
            if (attributes) {
                userId = attributes.user_attributes.Dreaming[0];
            }
            //console.log(userId);
            let dateTime = that.sportsservice.todayDateWithTime();
            let saveUserTrackData = { "userId": userId, "screenId": 0, "actionId": 2, "comment": "Logout" };//,"currentTimeStamp" : dateTime};
            //that.progress.requestStart();
            //users/network/lastaccessed?timeStamp=6/02/2017 05:54:22 PM
            that.lastAccessCall(that);
            that.sportsservice.getResponse('users/network/saveusertrack', 'post', saveUserTrackData)
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    // that.progress.requestEnd();
                },
                err => { //that.progress.requestEnd();
                }
                );
            let data = that.recentPinnedHistory.getRecentData('recentContract');
            if (data) {
                let postData = {
                    "recentHeros": data.recentData.recentHeros,
                    "pinnedHeros": data.recentData.pinnedHeros,
                    "pinnedContracts": data.recentData.pinnedContracts
                };

                that.sportsservice.getResponse("Heros/network/SPORTSRecentHeros", 'post', postData)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                    },
                    err => {
                        console.log("updating recent data failed");
                    }
                    );
            }

            that.sportsservice.clearSession();
            window.localStorage.removeItem("season");
            window.localStorage.removeItem("recentSPORTSHero");
            window.localStorage.removeItem("recentContract");
            window.sessionStorage.removeItem("userPrivilege");
            window.sessionStorage.removeItem("loginResponse");

            let baseUrl = window.location.hostname;
            //   let that = this;

            if (window.location.hostname == "localhost") {
                // let that = this;
                alert("I am here");

                baseUrl = 'qa.jumping.swimming.isports.com';
                //that.router.navigate('https://login.stg.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fjumping-auth.login.dancing.isports.com/logout.do?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F' #= baseUrl # '&client_id=oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo');


                that.router.navigate(['https://login.stg.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fjumping-auth.login.dancing.isports.com/logout.do?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F' + baseUrl + '&client_id=oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo']);

                //window.location.href = 'https://login.stg.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fjumping-auth.login.dancing.isports.com/logout.do?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F'+baseUrl+'&client_id=oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'; 

            } else {
                var envCheck;

                envCheck = window.location.hostname.split(".");

                if (envCheck[2].toLowerCase() == "swimming") {
                    window.location.href = 'https://login.stg.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fjumping-auth.login.dancing.isports.com/logout.do?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F' + baseUrl + '&client_id=oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo';
                }
                else if (envCheck[2].toLowerCase() == "stars") {
                    window.location.href = 'https://login.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fauth-domain.login.sysstars.isports.com/logout.do?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F' + baseUrl + '&client_id=8dfcf377-83b7-4d5d-b403-aa65b78229f2';
                }
                else if (envCheck[2].toLowerCase() == "bat") {
                    //TEmporary URL
                    window.location.href = 'https://login.stg.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fjumping-auth.login.dancing.isports.com/logout.do?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F' + baseUrl + '&client_id=oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo';
                }
                if (window.location.hostname == "new.jumping.isports.com") {
                    window.location.href = 'https://login.isports.com/Dreaminglogin/logoff.jsp?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fauth-domain.login.sysstars.isports.com/logout.do?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F' + baseUrl + '&client_id=8dfcf377-83b7-4d5d-b403-aa65b78229f2';
                }
            }

            //that.router.navigate(['/Base']);
            //location.reload();
        });
        $("#logoutNo").unbind().click(function () {
            newdialog.close();
        });

    }
```

Comment: `providing part of the code below` - is it the **relevant** part or just a random snippet? Because there's nothing to do with Promises in the code you posted, yet the error apparently occurs "in promise" ... `whole code in the gist` - do we need to search ourselves?

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry missed the gist...updated the gist

Comment: 404 - page not found

Comment: @JaromandaX I am trying to replace window.location.href with that.router.navigate

Comment: doesn't help the gist

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry...can you check now

Comment: can you? because it's still 404 this isn't the page you are looking for ... how hard is it to post a link!

Comment: @arar - i don't know whether it's possible... but is your gist publicly viewable? if it's marked as private or something, then everyone (but you) will get a 404.

Comment: This problem suggests that the Route for the link has not been defined. This error is throught by the ngRoute module. Post the code defining your routes and others will be better prepared to help.

Comment: @Matt can you update in my code...its so confusing

Comment: @all removed the gist...and replaced with codepen...can you help me

Comment: This complex of an application isn't going to work in a code pen as you need to reference a number of different files. Where are you getting this code from. It is an advanced example of a complex component, but it does not represent the Root of the application. Angular2+ relies on building on a solid Application Root Component, loading in sub-components from this initial App Component's template and/or dynamically swapping in components using a route, such as, ngRouter. If you are new to Angular, I would recommend starting by working through the example guide at https://angular.io/guide

Comment: What is `sportsservice.getResponse` is that a kendo method or something you wrote? Could you please point to the documentation of that method or post what that method does?